# Is it possible to detect which input field was invalid upon form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Using the code below, I am able to use `.on("invalid")` function to detect if there was an error with a field when submitting a form. If there was an error, I then check if both the `input` and `textarea` if either of them or empty, too long or too short and add the class `.error`.

However I am wondering if there is any way to simplify my code so that I don't have to run additional `if` statements inside the function.

```js
$("form input, form textarea").on("invalid", function(event) {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

  if (!input1.value || input1.value.length < 9 || input1.value.length > 69) {
    input1.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(function() {
      input1.classList.remove('error');
    }, 500);
  }

  if (!input2.value || input2.value.length < 21 || input2.value.length > 899) {
    input2.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(function() {
      input2.classList.remove('error');
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input1" minlength="8" maxlength="70" required>
  <textarea id="input2" maxlength="900" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is an example of what I am looking for, where `x` is the field (the input or textarea) which caused the form to be invalid.:

```
$("form input, form textarea").on("invalid", function(event) {
   x.classList.add('error'); // variable x
   setTimeout(function() {
      x.classList.remove('error'); // variable x
   }, 500);  
});
```

I would ideally like to stick to JavaScript, however I appreciate that jQuery may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution that doesn't exactly find the target with javascript, but uses the `oninvalid` event listener in html.

`<input type="text" oninvalid="alert('You must fill out the form!');" required>`

When the form returns invalid, instead of it being packaged as a form event, this will trigger as an input event. You can make it do whatever you like in javascript when that specific input is incorrect upon form submission.

Comment: Thanks John, this helped me solve my problem (with a few tweaks, I posted the answer to my question which you can see above) and I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Sure. If this solved your problem, please mark it solved if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp
The event onsubmit perhaps will be a better option. Is valid for all browsers

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninvalid.asp
Instead, if you use oninvalid you will find problems with the Safari browser

```
<form onsubmit="validateForm()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

function validateForm() {
    //your code here
    if(validationfails){
        return false; //if arrives here means the form won't be submited
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help solve the question unfortunately but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes srry. I hope it will be usefull for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, particularly thanks to the suggestion by John Paul Penaloza, by using `oninvalid` on the input and textarea field. I called a function which then added the class `.error` to the input field - it does the same as the code in my question, but simpler:

```js
function error(field) {
  field.classList.add('error');
  setTimeout(function() {
    field.classList.remove('error');
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input1" oninvalid="error(this);" minlength="8" maxlength="70" required>
  <textarea id="input2" oninvalid="error(this);" maxlength="900" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can think differently and offer real time error reporting.

Add an `id="myForm"` to your `<form>` element, and then use Js in a lines of:

```
var allInputs = $('#myForm :input');
var inputsFuked = []

allInputs.each(function( index ) {
    console.log(allInputs[index]);
  $(allInputs[index]).change(function() {
    if (allInputs[index].checkValidity()) inputsFuked[index]=1;
    else inputsFuked[index]=0;
    });
});
```

Here is working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo24gvex/) with couple of more elements without validation.

This will bind on change code to be executed every time some input changes. This is an example so it only toggles values in array. When you wanna validate, you simply check which are wrong. If you stored elements in array you could state which element. Simply switch toggle index logic to add/remove from array.

But with this contraption you can do way better, you can write instant reaction to invalid element. Instead changing index in array you could prompt alert, display error, make element red. Basically interact with the user the moment he focused out of element where he made input error instead doing it passively at some point after.